# logical operators in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, logical-operators

In my model to estimate the demand for a new product, I have a while loop to keep the variables in their ranges, but it is not working correctly.3 features or product variables that need to be always in a range  are weight, price and size. Is this condition for while correct?

```
while [(weight > 400) or (weight < 100)) and ((size < 5) or (size > 20)) and ((price > 90) or (price < 20))]
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the logic that you're trying to represent...like in English?

Comment: I want to optimize these three variables. In a local search procedure, the values of these variables keep changing, and I want to make sure, they are still in the range. The range is : 100<weight<400 , 5<size<20, 20<price<90

Comment: Does the while loop execute until the values are in range? or do you want to loop until they are out of range?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, It seems your logic is off.

For example, if you have a weight, `w`, it means that `w` has to be between 400 and 100. So, `(w < 400 and w > 100)`

The following will tell if all the variables are within their respective ranges. 
`weight  < 400 and weight > 100 and size < 20 and size > 5 and price < 90 and price > 20`.

Be aware that `size` is a default turtle attribute.

If you want to negate that, just put a not in the front surrounding everything else by parenthesis.
`not (weight  < 400 and weight > 100 and size < 20 and size > 5 and price < 90 and price > 20)`

You may want to look into De Morgan's Law.

For the record, here's the equivalent of the negation by pushing the not through:

```
weight >= 400 or weight <= 100 or size >= 20 or size <= 5 or price >= 90 or price <= 20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know about using "not" this way. I actually wanted the while loop to do this : while the variables are not in range, it decreases the step size. I defined it like this :  while [not(((weight <= 400) and (weight >= 100)) and ((sizex >= 5) and sizex <= 20)) and ((price >= 20) and (price <=90)))]
    [
     set stepsize1 stepsize1 - 0.0001]                                                                     It sounds reasonable now, but the optimization is not working.

Comment: I don't see anything in your while loop relating to your stepsize. Is there other code?

Comment: Sorry that my question was not much clear. I defined a stepsize in the setup procedure. Then I created this while loop to check if the variables are in range or not. If they are not , it is supposed to make the stepsize smaller and calculate the variables again.

Comment: How is your optimization computed? Try breaking up your code into small testable components. You can use the netlogo testing extension and/or put print statements.

Comment: I have kind of broken it up, but the problem is with the optimization procedure. I will ask questions about that seperately.